# Solving following second order matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

Which methods (analytical or numerical) do you suggest to solve the following matrix diff. equation? And why? (Presumably analytical method)

$$ \textbf{M}\ddot{V}+\textbf{C}\dot{V}+\textbf{K}V=\textbf{P},$$
where matrices $\ddot{V}$, $\dot{V}$ and $V$ with respect to $t$ are as follows:
$$ \mathbf{M} \begin{bmatrix} \ddot{V}(1,t) \\ \ddot{V}(2,t) \\ \vdots \\ \ddot{V}(n,t) \end{bmatrix} +\mathbf{C} \begin{bmatrix} \dot{V}(1,t) \\ \dot{V}(2,t) \\ \vdots \\ \dot{V}(n,t) \end{bmatrix} +\mathbf{K} \begin{bmatrix} V(1,t) \\ V(2,t) \\ \vdots \\ V(n,t) \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{P}.$$

In here, the matrices $\textbf{M}$, $\textbf{C}$, $\textbf{K}$ and $\textbf{P}$ are as follows ($\textbf{M}$, $\textbf{C}$ and $\textbf{K}$ are $n \times n$ matrices, and  $\textbf{V}$, $\textbf{P}$, $\textbf{F}$ are $n \times 1$ matrices) 
[image]

$$\mathbf{P} = \frac{P}{\rho A} \begin{bmatrix} \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi vt}{l}\right) \\ \sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi vt}{l}\right) \\ \vdots \\ \sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi vt}{l}\right) \end{bmatrix} +\mathbf{F}(t), \quad\text{where } \mathbf{F}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} f_1(t) \\ f_2(t) \\ \vdots \\ f_n(t) \end{bmatrix}.$$

In here, $l$, $P$, $A$, $\rho$, $\alpha$, $v$, $N$, $E$ and $I$ are constants. It doesn't matter what are these constants or initial or boundary conditions for me. You can select appropriate values. The matrix $\textbf{F}(t)$ is ungiven. So solution $\textbf{V}$ will depend on $\textbf{F}$.

Comment: Can you write dimensions of matrices explicitly? As far as I've understood it is $\mathbf{M}, \mathbf{C}, \mathbf{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\mathbf{P}, V \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it correct?

Comment: You are right. I edited.

Comment: You can employ the usual methods of differential equations, which really makes it a problem of finding a particular solution to the original (non-homogenous) equation.

Comment: Don't most solvers want first-order systems? To get to that form I would let $\begin{bmatrix}\dot V\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}W\end{bmatrix}$ so that $$\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&M\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot V\\\dot W\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&-I\\K&C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V\\W\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\P\end{bmatrix}$$ Not to mention that you trashed your earlier image with your last edit. Rendering your matrices in Mathjax would make life easier.

Comment: This looks like something that would be converted to a quadratic eigenvalue problem after discretization.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Can you clarify this bit? What's really confusing me here is that all matrices are periodic w.r.t. $t$. I understand that Floquet theorem is still applicable to the system of first order equations, but can something really be said analytically?

Comment: @Evgeny, yes, Floquet would likely apply here, but my comment was more about thinking on how to *numerically* solve this; the OP had posted a question on this at the Mathematica site. user5713492's comment shows Wilkinson's method for possibly handling it as a quadratic eigenproblem.